# .NET verify format string for a dynamic type

Tags: .net, regex, string, formatting

I would appreciate some aid in getting the last piece solved  please. What I want is to read from configuration the **TYPE, VALUE and FORMATSTRING** to be applied on the VALUE.

In Code, what I am trying to do is

a) Verify the TYPE specified is a correct CLR recognized type

```
 var o = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(TYPE));
if(o == null)
    return false; 
//continue
```

b) Dynamically cast the specified VALUE to make sure that my the VALUE AND TYPE will work.

```
  dynamic val = Convert.ChangeType(VALUE, t);
              //now make sure the format String works for the specified type
```

c) finally, format VALUE using the specified FORMATSTRING

```
 ????????????
```

Currently I have

if (String.Format("{0:" + formatString + "}", val.ToString()) != null)
                      return true;

How do you validate a format string will work for a particular type, especially on a dynamic instance of that type? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Why not just try the format and catch the exception if it doesn't work?

Format throws a specific FormatException if it is wrong.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception.aspx